# readYaml() not working properly with integers in yml file

Tags: groovy, yaml

I have this simple test.yml file:

`version: 1.10`

println yaml.version output:

`1.1`

Why does this happen and how to workaround this?

Comment: 1.10 is not an integer. It would be best to use `String`type instead of numbers for versions if you intend to have versions like `1.10`, `1.100` and etc...

Comment: thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `1.10` isn't an integer, it's a floating point with a value of `1.1`.  So when you print the number, the trailing zero is being dropped.  Perhaps you want to make the version a string: `version: '1.10'`